# How do you unlock each of the Arms Manufacturers?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

There are 8 of them in total, but how do you get each of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can unlock half of them by doing the story, and the other half require you to do missions.

The ones you unlock via the story are:

- **Sakuraba Industries** (complete chapter 3)
- **Grenada Galactic Group** (complete chapter 3)
- **Meredith & Co.** (complete chapter 4)
- **Candid & Credible** (complete chapter 5)

There are some that have quest chains associated with them:

- **Six Stars** requires you to complete two affinity missions: "Prospective Partners" and "A Challenger Approaches" (both available via the BLADE barracks), and you have to have completed chapter 11. You'll have to be around level 40-45 to complete this chain.
- **Orphean Technologies** requires you to complete a normal mission "Rock Base Rescue Operation" (talk to Julius near the BLADE tower to get this mission).
- **Nopon Commerce Guild** requires you to complete the "BFFs" affinity mission (which first requires you complete "The Ties That Bind" affinity mission).
- **Factory 1.21** requires you to complete "Professor B's Return" (which first requires you to complete the "Mystery Man" normal mission, found in the industrial district).